# django tries to read from wrong DB table

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

Here is my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'mydbname',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '#IP Address that your DB is hosted on'
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

My model is :

```
class Center(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    englishName = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    website     = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And here is the error I see when I try t fetch the data from the DB :

```
Table `mydbname.dashboard_center` does not exist.
```

dashboard is the name of my django app. Why does it append it to the table name?

My original table name in my DB is `center`

Note that:
* DB configuration is correct - I am using it in ohter php files.
* DB is legacy - I only want to read data from it.

Why does it append the app name? Should I put somewhere the table names or should there be 1-to-1 match between models and table names?

It is my first django app and I am going through the tutorial but I am trying to adjust it on my own stuff.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that.

I ran this :

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb
```

and found out what my models need to be. It seems that the difference was the :

```
class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'Center'
```

that was missing.

[Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/) for the official documentation about using a legacy DB.